# Modular Arithmetic Problem: 108  ≡4 (mod254)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

108  ≡ 4 (mod254)

The solutions are {80,207} and I don't understand why. Can someone walk me through this modular arithmetic problem?

Comment: What part do you not understand? Do you not understand why $108\cdot 80\cong 5\pmod 254$, or do you not understand how $80$ was found in the first place?

Comment: Do you know the definition of $ax\equiv b\bmod c$?

Comment: To me it looks like the solution should rather be $x\equiv 80\pmod{127}$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- divide the equation by $2$ to reduce it to $\pmod{127}$ prime
- apply totient function to invert $54$ i.e calculate $54^{-1}=54^{125}$
- use $54^2\equiv -5$ and $5^3\equiv -2$ and $2^7\equiv 1$ modulo $127$ to simplify this calculation
- multiply the equation by the reduced value of $54^{-1}$ to get your result
- edit your post with the calculation and you'll receive help if you are stuck

Answer (score -2):

$108x = 254y + 4$  That's what a *modulus* means and ...

$108 \times 80 = 254 \times 34 + 4$

Similarly ...

$108 \times 207 = 254 \times 88 + 4$

Imagine a *clock* with 254 hours. What o'clock is it $108 \times 207$ hours from midnight? What time is it $108 \times 80$ hours after midnight? In both cases, the time is $4$ (the *remainder*).

Thank you for the question.